# Removing Duplicates from linked list. Why are the position of "prev = head" and "p2 = p2.next" not outside the else statement?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

For the first function, shouldn't "prev = head" be outside of else because we want to set the previous every time before we change the head value?

For the second function, shouldn't "p2 = p2.next" be outside of else because we want to go next every time?

Thank you guys.

```
    //This would take O(n) but would require extra space O(n)
    public static Node removeDuplicates(Node head){
        Node prev = null;
        Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>();
        
        while(head!= null){
            if(hs.contains(head.data)){
                prev.next = head.next;
            }
            else{
                hs.add(head.data);
                //why is prev = head here instead of out of the else statement? 
                prev = head;
            }
            head = head.next;
        }
        return head;
    }

    //This would take O(n^2) but no extra space is required.
    public static Node removeDuplicatesTradeOff(Node head){
        //pointer 1 and pointer 2.
        Node p1 = head;

        while(p1.next != null){
            Node p2 = p1;
            while(p2.next != null){
                if(p1.data == p2.next.data){
                    p2.next = p2.next.next;
                }
                else{
                    //why is p2 = p2.next here instead of out of the else statement? 
                    p2 = p2.next;
                }  
            }
            p1 = p1.next;
        }

        return head;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't "p2 = p2.next" be outside of else because we want to go next every time

I think it would be more accurate to say that we want to **have a different next available every time**, instead of saying that we want to "go next" every time.

We don't always want to "go next". When `prev.next` has changed due to another operation (in this case removal of a duplicate) we want to stay where we are, because `prev.next` has already changed and is now pointing to a node further ahead (because a duplicate node has just been removed).

In other words, we don't want to have a different `prev` every time, we just want to have a different `prev.next` every time. So as long as `prev.next` advances every time, we don't care if `prev` stays the same sometimes.

That's why in both methods `prev` (or `p2`) only advances in the `else` branch, while `prev.next` (or `p2.next`) is updated (advances) only in the `if` branch.

Think of these two as different operations, the `else` branch being "go next" and the `if` branch being "drop next". When you drop a node ahead of you, you did not move (true!), but since you did drop one node ahead of you, now there is a new node ahead of you, so did not have to move. So you can just continue with `if/else` checks and sooner or later you will reach the end or you will drop the last node ahead of you.

One input example to illustrate this point is

```
head(1) -> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> null
```

With such an input, the algorithm would only do

- drop next
- drop next
- drop next

and it would be done.

No "go next" happened at all.

Result

```
head(1) -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

Using solution 1 as a reference because the answer applies to both solutions. When you find a duplicate at the current node (`head`), you set the previous node’s (`prev`) `next` node to the current node’s `next` node (which removes the duplicate). On the next iteration, you will go to the next node in the list which is already being pointed at by the previous node. So, there is no need to overwrite `prev`. Another way to think about it is that the `head` you would be setting `prev` to is the node that you just removed. You wouldn’t want to do that.

Before removal:
node1 (prev) -> node2(head) -> node3

After removal:
node1 (prev) -> node3 (head)

As you can see, `prev` stays the same. No need to update it.

Answer (score 0):

***`removeDuplicates`:***

If we remove a duplicate, the current removed node should *not* be assigned to `prev`. In fact `prev` is the previous node in the remaining kept list of uniques.

As is entirely evident, when there are more than 2 repeated values.

```
... -> prev: [42] -> [42] -> [42] -> [51] -> ...
```

should become

```
... -> prev: [42] -> [51] -> ...
```

***removeDuplicatesTradeOff:***

The same case. `p2` (the previous node) may only advance when no duplicate was found.

***Then there is a tiny bug:***

`removeDuplicates` should return the new `head` normally - in case the head node is removed:

```
head = remove...(head); // Must assign, should the head node itself be removed.
```

Now it returns `null`. However for duplicates, the head node is never deleted. So either make it a `void` function or return the old `head`.

```
public static Node removeDuplicates(Node head){
    Node prev = null;
    Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();

    Node current = head;
    // Loop-invariant: hs.isEmpty() || prev != null
    while (current != null) {
        if (hs.contains(current.data)) {
            prev.next = current.next;
        } else {
            hs.add(current.data);
            prev = current;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Also notice that it is bad style using the name `head` for a running pointer.